# How do you set a component property from within a thread without throwing an error in C# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a user interface which needs to be updated by a function running in a `backgroundworker` (a different thread from the primary one).

I would like to **effectively** be able to do the following without throwing an exception:

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        MyProgresssbar.value = val;
        MyLabel.text = "Still going...";
    }
```

For example, could a delegate function be written that sets a component property (I don't want to have a function for each property change).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use BackgroundWorker's built-in progress reporting functionality.

As a more general answer, you can run code in the UI thread (aynchronously) by calling

```
someControl.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate { ... }));
```